# VirtualboxでのゲストOSのIPアドレス固定方法

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualboxにWindows7をインストールして、都合によりゲストOSのWindows7にサーバーを立てたいと考えております。
　ホストOS: Ubuntu
　ゲストOS: Windows7

しかし、以下の手順でゲストOSのWindows7のIPを固定しましたが、ネットワークにアクセスできない状態です。アドバイスをいただきたく。

1. Virtualboxの「ファイル」→「環境設定」→「ネットワーク」→「ホストオンリーネットワーク」で追加する。
   [image]
2. 仮想マシンの「設定」→「ネットワーク」でアダプタ２に「ホストオンリーアダプタ」を設定
   　　（アダプタ１はNAT)
3. ゲストOSのWindows7を起動し、Ubuntuにて
   ping 192.168.56.1でpingが通ることは確認し、
   　　その後、IPアドレスを固定するために以下のように設定したが、ゲストOSでネットワークが接続できない。

   現状は以下です。
   　　　・ホストOS(192.168.11.10)からゲストOS(192.168.56.2)へpingが通らない。
   　　　・ゲストOS(192.168.56.2)からホストOS(192.168.11.10)へpingが通らない。
   　　　　ゲストOSのWindows7側のファイアウォールを無効にしても症状変わらず。

   [image]

Comment: `ネットワークにアクセスできない` とありますがどのような状態が理想ですか?ホストオンリーネットワークは名前の通りHost--Guestsの内部ネットワークなるものですが…

Comment: ネットワークに接続できないとは、ホストOSから192.168.56.2にpingが通らないのです。

Comment: ゲートウエイ、DNSのアドレスとして１９２．１６８．５６．`０`が指定されていますけど、ホスト番号０番は一般に使用出来ません。原因の１つだと思います。

Comment: dnsは、デフォルトゲートウェイと同じではダメ？ということでしょうか？

Comment: 192.168.56.「0」←この部分が 0 であるのが問題である、ということかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ホストオンリーアダブタのIPアドレスが192.168.56.1なので、
ゲスト側のIPを192.168.56.101, デフォルトゲートウエイ、優先DNSサーバーを
192.168.56.2にしてみましたが、ホストOSからゲストOSにpingが通りませんでした。修正の仕方が間違ってますでしょうか？

Comment: デフォルトゲートウェイを 192.168.56.1 にしてみてください。

Comment: デフォルトゲートウエイを192.168.56.1にしてみましたが、ゲストOSからホストOSの192.168.11.10にpingが通りません。

Comment: ホストオンリーなのでそういうものなのではないでしょうか。ゲストからホスト(192.168.56.1) への ping は通ると思います。

Comment: ゲストOSのネットワーク「（アダプタ１はNAT)」と書かれてますが、アダプタ１を無効化して、アダプタ２のデフォルトゲートウェイを消して見てください。その状態で、192.168.56.2 -> 192.168.56.1 へPingは通りますか？ WindowsのPingは「/S」で送信元IPを指定できますので「ping /S 192.168.56.2 192.168.56.1」で試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

ゲストOSのファイアウォールで落とされているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: すいません。ファイアウォールで、落とされているかは、どのように調べたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず、ファイアウォールを無効にしてみるのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ファイアウォールを無効にしてもダメでした。
元々の質問に追記しましたが、ホストOS⇔ゲストOSのpingが通らないので困ってます。